# SendEmail is not working in Selenium Webdriver - Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com;

Tags: java, email, selenium-webdriver, proxy, smtp

My code is working perfectly if am not behind any firewall. But when i have executed same code from the network which is behind any firewall (company network) its not working and throws exceptions.

**Below is my code -**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String emailbody = Utilities.getProperty("BASE_MESSAGE").replace("<<PROJECT_NAME>>",Utilities.getProperty("PROJECT_NAME"));
    emailbody += "\n\n Environment: ";
    emailbody += "\n\nTest Cases Executed: 7 " ;
    emailbody += "\nTest Cases Passed: 5" ;
    emailbody += "\nTest Cases Failed: 2";
    emailbody += "\nTest Cases Skipped: 0";
    emailbody += "\n\nAttached is the detailed report. Please reach out to Automation Team for more details.";
    emailbody += "\n\nRegards,\nAutomation Team";
    emailsend(emailbody);

}



/**
 * Function to Send an Emial
 * @param emailbody
 */
public static void emailsend(String emailbody) {
    final String usernameFrom = Utilities.getProperty("EMAIL_USER_NAME");
    final String password = Utilities.getProperty("EMAIL_PASSWORD");
    // Create object of Property file       
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "true");

    // This will handle the complete authentication
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator()
    {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(usernameFrom, password);
        }
    });

    try {

        // Create object of MimeMessage class
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(usernameFrom));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("xxxx@yy.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");

        // Create object to add multimedia type content
        BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart1.setText(emailbody);
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
        String filename = "C:\\Users\\test.xlsx";

        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart2.setFileName(filename);
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);
        message.setContent(multipart);
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("=====Email Sent=====");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {

        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    }

}
```

**Exception -** 
javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

> SendEmail is not working in Selenium Webdriver

Selenium WebDriver has no connection with sending email. Both are from different java packages.

> Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com

This is actual issue.

> My code is working perfectly if am not behind any firewall. But when i have executed same code from the network which is behind any firewall (company network) its not working and throws exceptions.

This clearly says that your company network blocks access to smtp.gmail.com

You can verify this by simple *ping* command.

```
$ ping smtp.gmail.com
```

Result of ping on network with access:

```
$ ping smtp.gmail.com
PING smtp.gmail.com (74.125.24.109): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 74.125.24.109: icmp_seq=0 ttl=42 time=80.973 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.24.109: icmp_seq=1 ttl=42 time=89.877 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.24.109: icmp_seq=2 ttl=42 time=94.582 ms
```

Result of ping on network without access:

```
$ ping smtp.gmail.com
PING smtp.gmail.com (74.125.24.109): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
```

Hope this helps.